# Dojo: remove all element listeners or having singleton-listener

Tags: javascript, dojo, listener

Imagine that every 5 seconds we refresh the page and rebuild the list of items. After list has been rebuilt we would like to assign an event listener for each item:

```
refreshContent: function() {
  array.forEach(items, function(item) {
    on(item, 'click', function() {
      // do something
    });
  });
}
```

The problem is that some items already have event listeners and get duplicate.

Is there any way to clear all previous listeners for the item or have *singleton* listener?

Comment: there is a `once` function in the `dojo/on` module, which will be called only one time and the handler will be removed after. Documentation [here](http://livedocs.dojotoolkit.org/dojo/on#once)

Comment: @frank : `once` is not for the same purpose. `once` disconnect after event is fired. It does not prevent attaching 2 times the same event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to keep track of events you attached then you can detach them :

```
refreshContent: function() {
  if(handles) {
       //clean up old handle
       array.forEach(handles, function(handle) {
           handle.remove();
       });
  }
  //save all handles in this variable
  handles = [];
  array.forEach(items, function(item) {
    handles.push(on(item, 'click', function() {
      // do something
    }));
  });
}
```

Comment: After trying different solutions, looks like this one is the one to be used for connects inside a loop.